# Comparing Byte Arrays in LINQ to Objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, comparison, linq-to-objects

In a LINQ query:

```
from c in results
where c.ByteField == byteData
select c;
```

I'm getting no results from this even though the bytes are the same:

byte[5] = 49, 50, 51, 52, 53

How do I compare bytes properly in LINQ to Objects?

Thanks.

Comment: @Axarydax - I wouldn't call that related. That answer properly tests length and that the same elements are in the array...but ignores sequence. In the OPs case, sequence matters as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In LINQ to Objects (as your post suggests in the title), you can use [`IEnumerable.SequenceEqual()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx):

```
from c in results
where c.ByteField.SequenceEqual(byteData)
select c;
```

Unfortunately, it looks like you're using LINQ to SQL (or Entity Framework) based on your use of `context`. There's no SQL equivalent of SequenceEqual so this won't work in that case.

Comment: Oops, I didn't mean to have that there, it is actually LINQ to Objects.  Thanks.

Comment: There are no array properties in LINQ-to-SQL (or Entity Framework) either, so that would be a non-issue.

Comment: Not true - VARBINARY maps to byte[].

Comment: Timestamp also maps to byte[].